# C++20 coroutines and ILP

Tags: c++, performance, c++20, coroutine

I was thinking about the following fact:

**NOTE:** I don't know if that has a name already but let's call "filaments" to any of the "streams" of instructions that can be executed in parallel within a same logic core: the idea of thread, but lowered to the level of instruction parallelism.

- Suppose that you have two functions `f1` and `f2` that are independent to each other.
- Imagine that the CPU have the ability to compute up to 5 filaments of instructions, but `f1` have only 3 filaments in its most parallelizable part, and `f2` only 2 filaments.
- Computing `f1` followed by `f2` (or viceversa) won't use the maximum computing capacity of the core ever.
- However, why don't execute both functions at the same time in the same core to offer the CPU plenty of filaments to schedule?
- I know compilers merge loops and things like that precisely to achieve that purpose, but I guess it won't do that for different functions.

However, if using coroutines, the programmer has already "split" its whole functionality in "concurrent filaments" and also explain how they correlate to each other (by specifying its synchronization points with `co_yield`, etc). That information is priceless. Coudn't that be used by compilers to multiply by 100x its ability to exploit the CPU's ILV capacities?

**Example:**
Imagine `f1` contains three subsections of code creating a dependence chain, and `f2` four subsections creating a another dependence chain:

- `f1`: A B C
- `f2`: D E F G

If, in addition, `f1` and `f2` are independent to each other, what you want the CPU to see is (f1 in bold):

- D **A** E **B** F **C** G

however, executing `f1(); f2()` causes the CPU to see the following stream of blocks of instructions (at least in my mental mode of how I think things work):

- **A B C** D E F G

If `f1` and `f2` are "big" functions, even if they are implement in the same module, they won't be marked as inline, and so the compiler can't interleave its execution either (because, if `f1` and `f2` are non-inlined regular functions, how would you interleave its executions if only one function can have the control at any given time?), and the CPU won't find parallelism there because the stream **A B C** D is probably too big to fit into the reorder buffer and `D` won't have a chance to be parallelized with `A`.

If `f1` and `f2` are coroutines, and each "block" is separated by the following one by some "synchronization primitive" (for example A to B and D to E by `co_yield` or `co_await`), that's a powerful hint that A and D are parallelizable.

Comment: What makes you think that doesn't already happen? "I guess it won't do that for different functions" have you heard of inlining?

Comment: It's probably much easier for the compiler to do this with regular inlined code where it can see all the data dependencies, than it is with a bunch of coroutines. The only obvious way to parallelize coroutines is to move some to a different thread, and schedule that on the other hyperthread on the same core

Comment: @Useless I have added a example to show, at least based on how I see the situation, the limitations respect to inlining.

Comment: @Caleth Same. I have added an example citing a situation where inlining is not possible.

Comment: Why do you think inlining is not possible for "big" functions? Especially with profile-guided optimisations, I don't know if there is an upper limit on function size where the compiler won't consider inlining

Comment: I think you have confused coroutines with threads. Coroutine blocks run sequentially, and one block can (and usually does) depend on the result of the preceding block of the other coroutine.

Comment: @Caleth I'm just exploring the realm of possibilities, but yes, inlining is a good counter-argument (although it depends on whether the different functions are in the same module or not).

Comment: @RaymondChen but it also allows to interleave execution of different functions in a block-based manner (one block of you, one block of me, one block of you, one block of me), without barely breaking the semantics/readability of the functions.

Comment: @RaymondChen  By the locality principle, I guess the closer 2 instructions are, the more likely they depend on the data both are manipulating. If I want to have several blocks defined in different functions, but at the same time there are "sub-blocks" that are independent to each other (or their dependences is very low), I thing is not stupid to "hint" the CPU to extract parallelism by exploring these two separated blocks of instructions rather than from instructions that are much closer together and would have a bigger likehood of creating dependence chains.

Comment: @RaymondChen also without having to pay the price of creating and managing threads, of being careful about data races, and without consuming more cache space since each thread will be populating its own stuff in the L1 cache of different cores (where maybe in a single core I have still space to parallelize more, just from code that are away from each other and whose dependences would be satisfied quickly).

Comment: @ABu "inlining is a good counter-argument (although it depends on whether the different functions are in the same module or not)" - With LTO (Link Time Optimization) the compiler can inline (and perform other optimizations) across translation unit boundaries.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes I know, but it could also potentially increase compilation times a lot.

Comment: @ABu In my experience - unless you have a *massive* code base, the extra time spent on LTO is negligible compared to the performance improvements it gives you as well as the (often) smaller binary sizes. But that's just opinion - fact of the matter is that compilers *can* inline and optimize across translation unit boundaries.